# ajax request returns 10 responses per second

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, return

Depending on what ajax returns ( 1 or 0 ), I want the submit-action to be processed or not:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    if(username){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'checkinput.php',
            data: {data: JSON.stringify(username)},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.result == 0) {
                    alertify.log( data.error ); // diplay error
                }
                if(data.result == 1) {
                    $("#submit").submit(); // process submit-action => send data to php etc..
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        alertify.log( "forgotten something" );
    }    
  });
});
```

If the returned result from the php-script is 0, than the error-message is displayed and the page is not refreshed ( GREAT ) <= It should be like this.

If Ajax returns 1, I want the submit action to be processed, so data can be send to php.
But what happens:

Ajax sends 10 responses per second (maybe because of the function I call in the if-clause ? )
If the returned result is 1, I want the submit-action to be processed.
How to solve this?

Comment: You used `$("#submit").submit(function(e){...` and `$("#submit").submit();` This results an infinite loop. Instead I would use form submit button to fire the jQuery block then use `$("#submit").submit();` if return value is `1`

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop because `$("#submit").submit()` triggers the submit `event`. what you want instead is to submit the form without triggering the event. Lucky for you, that just means adding 3 characters to your code, `[0]`.

```
$("#submit")[0].submit();
```

Comment: thanks for jooning this issue, when i do this, the following happens: returned.result == 1 (good), but i get this typeError: "TypeError: $(...)[0].submit is not a function", could you refer to this?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you need to give your form a different id than "submit". This is a known issue that is caused by a *feature* of the browser. The only fix to it is to not use "submit" as an id name.