# Check returned data from ajax/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, return

I did an update with [all things you told me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549709/ajax-request-returns-10-responses-per-second), this is my result.
COMPLETE UPDATE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").submit(function(e){

e.preventDefault();

var username = $("#username").val();
var result;
var request;

if(username){
    request = $.ajax({
        url: 'check.php',
        data: {data: JSON.stringify(username)},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            result = data;
        }
    });
} else {
    alertify.error( "ERROR" );
}

request.done(function() {
    console.log(result);
    if(request.result == 1) {
        alert("yes")
    } else {
        alert("no")
    }
});
});
});
```

check.php:

```
$usernameChecker = new UsernameChecker($config);

$data = $_POST['data'];
$data = json_decode($data,true);

if(!empty($data)) {
    if ($usernameChecker->check_regex($data)) {
        if($usernameChecker->check_length($data)) {
            if (!$usernameChecker->check($data)) {
                echo json_encode(array("error" => "Username already taken" , "result" => 0));
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array("error" => "Username available" , "result" => 1));
            }
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array("error" => "Username too long" , "result" => 0));
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "Allowed symbols: a-z , A-Z , 1-9 and \"_\"" , "result" => 0));
    }
} else { 
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "You forgot to type your username" , "result" => 0));
}
```

This is what I have now, just console says:

> "result is not defined"

SO:

When I submit empty input, I get request is undefined.

When I submit filled input, I get alert "no". Moreover this part:

> "Username available"

is marked red.

But data.result is "1" in console?

Comment: It appears that the code is already doing that, you just don't do anything with it...

Comment: i edited the code, take a look at the bottom and you´ll see what i mean

Answer (score 3):

Assign data to another variable to use outside of the $.ajax function

```
var username = $("#username").val();
var result;
var request;
if(username){
    request = $.ajax({
        url: 'check.php',
        data: {data: JSON.stringify(username)},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            result = data;
        }
    });

} else {
    alertify.error( "ERROR" );      
}
```

Here is the edit for you

```
request.done(function() {
    console.log(result.result);
    if(result.result == 1) {
        alert("yes")
    } else {
        alert("no")
    }
});
```

Comment: if i alert "result", i get "undefined", how can i solve this?

Comment: The success function probably isn't firing. You can intialize result... var result = -1; Or something like that, if you're getting that answer, then success isn't firing. You can also use the .fail function to see if that fires

Comment: more than likely, this function is expecting json back, but you aren't sending back json. Try changing your response to be a json object

Comment: success function works, there is a POST and a RESPONSE in the console, you have any idea´s ?

Comment: What happens if you console.log(data) in the success function?

Comment: if i log, i get this: Object { error="Username available", result=1}

Comment: "Username available" <- this part is red

Comment: What does your PHP look like, what's it supposed to return?

Comment: i posted the php-code in the question, could you refer to it?

Comment: Ok looks good. Where I put the comment // now use result here, you should have no problem doing console.log(result) and get the exact same thing if you console.log(data) in the success function. I bet when you log it, it's getting called before the success function fires

Comment: i edited last time, could you take a look? if i get data.result == 1, the alert is "no", why?

Comment: result is the name of the variable, but also the name of your key. You want this instead:  if(result.result == 1)
{
alert("yes")
} else {
alert("no")
}  In the sample code you put up there, you used console.log(result) == 1, since you're using console.log() that is never going to be true, that's why it's going into the else

Comment: in your case "request" is not defined, where do i have to define it?

Comment: did you add in the edit it put in to make sure the ajax function is done? If you dont wanna do that you can add async: false, do your ajax function. It'll block until it's done

Comment: id did a complete update, thats the code now, you know why result not defined?

Comment: You forgot to update this piece - request = $.ajax({ oh and put the if statement that you're executing in the done function Also it's supposed to be request.done not result.done

Comment: changed both things => console say´s result is undefinded..mhm..sure i can do it that way?

Comment: sorry, result is just undefined if i submit an empty input, if i submit filled input, than i get: Object { error="Username available", result=1} , but this part is red marked: "Username available" , why?

Comment: OH if you submit empty input! Please show PHP again. Then I will have an answer for you.

Comment: I think that is in red simply because you prefixed it with the 'error' keyword, so the console is just like oh, this is an error, i need to make this red. Try changing the name and I bet it wont be red. To your other problem of sending empty data. I would be curious if PHP actually thinks it is empty data. Does the else actually get called?

Comment: yes it gets called, but thats not important, could you refer to my last if-clause? why do i get alert("no") ? when console say´s : result = 1 ?

Comment: Yes, put this if(request.result == 1) {
    alert("yes")
} else {
    alert("no")
}
});
}); in the .done function where the console.log is called. It is because that code is getting called before the $.ajax function is done

Comment: Just noticed a typo in two places in my edit. Take a look now. Before it said: console.log(result) and if (request.result)